# Using QueryParams in Angular route

Tags: angular, angular-routing

So I have a Back-End that's in charge of sending confirmation emails to users when they create an account, the email has a format like: `http://localhost:8080/confirm?token=`

I then want to have route with the same format on my Front-End side (which is made with Angular), so my question is how this url should be represented in my application routes. I'm currently trying to use `{ path: 'confirm', paramMap: { token : token } }` but not sure this is the best way to handle this, this is my first time doing something like this so I'd appreciate any input :)

I later need to use that token value in a service so I need a way to obtain its value in the "confirm" component or something.

Comment: You don't include the parameters in the routing. If the component needs to access the query params, it can subscribe to them via the `ActivatedRoute`. I'd recommend reading https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: Do you know of any example uses?

Comment: There are literally some in the documentation. That's what it's for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject the ActivatedRoute in your Component constructor and then access params using ActivatedRoute  instance.

```
    export class TestComponent Implements OnInit
    {
     token:string;
    constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute)
    {
    }
   ngOnInit()
   {
    route.params.subscribe((params:Params)=>{
      this.token=params['token'];
      //Or call your service to load the resource you need.
   })

   }
}
```

This is just sample example.

Answer (score 1):

I have an example of using query parameters here: https://github.com/DeborahK/MovieHunter-routing

As Jon stated, you don't specify query parameters in the route configuration:

[image]

UPDATE: Updated the screen shot to correct a typo and for latest syntax.